# Perl NET_RAWIP send Hexadecimal packet

Tags: perl, packet

so I have this code snippet, from a friend:

```
my $dnspacket = new Net::DNS::Packet($str, "A", "IN");
    my $dnsdata = $dnspacket->data;
    my $sock = new Net::RawIP({udp=>{}});
    $str = @name[int rand($names)];
    $reflector = $nameservers[int rand($reflectors)];          
    $sock->set({ip => {
                saddr => "127.0.0.1", daddr => "$r", frag_off=>0,tos=>0,id=>1565},
                udp => {source => 53,
                dest => 53, data=>$dnsdata
                } });
    $sock->send;
```

Bascially what I want to do, is instead of sending $dnsdata as the data in the packet, I want to send the hexidecimal data /x53/x41/x4d/x50/x25/xdd/xaf/xd3/x61/x1e/x63

How would I go about doing this? THanks!

Comment: Could be hex character ordinances `my $encoded = join('', map{sprintf('/x%02x', ord $_)} split('', $dnsdata))`. But you really need a specification, or at least some examples as to how the data should be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this :

```
$dnsdata =~ s!([\s\S])! sprintf("/%02x",ord($1)) !eg;
```

This is similar to the comment by snoopy except that split>join is not nice.